# Publish .NET 8 service as native (AOT) inside docker

Tags: .net, docker, native, .net-8.0

I'm trying to build a .NET service native using the AOT feature.

At the moment I am be able to build the `Dockerfile`, but when I check the content of the start-up container I notice that I have no `Application.dll` for start the container correctly, but a file with the same name but no extension.

**Dockerfile**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y clang zlib1g-dev

# RestApiPort
EXPOSE 5067
# OPC Port
EXPOSE 48031

RUN dotnet restore "Application.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/Application"
RUN dotnet build "Application.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Application.csproj" -c Release --self-contained false -r linux-x64 -o /app/publish /p:AOT=true /p:UseAppHost=false
RUN rm /app/publish/*.dbg /app/publish/*.Development.json

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

USER root

ENTRYPOINT ["./Application"]
```

NOTE: `/p:AOT` is a custom flag to enable `PublishAot` and `PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest` on csproj

Comment: That's that native Linux binary created for your application, which doesn't have a file extension normally. So that's exactly what you want with native AOT. What exactly is the question/ problem?

Comment: I think it was wrong that service could not start without dotnet...but when I try to startup a container seems to start, but when I check for it, I dont see it

UPDATE
It returns the following error
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions'.

Comment: I resolved by adding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions package